# Entity Framework entity can't be found in dbcontext auto-generated code

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, entity-framework

I use entity framework 6.1.3 model first approach.
I needed to design a simple model as [following](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86iZX.jpg).

Then i generated sql to create the database but i found that my entities sets were not defined in my DbContext. I tried to add them manually but Entity Framework keeps regenerating the following code.
It only generates the abstract entity which is exactly the opposite of what it is designed for.

```
public partial class UploadsDataModelContainer : DbContext
{
    public UploadsDataModelContainer()
        : base("name=UploadsDataModelContainer")
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        throw new UnintentionalCodeFirstException();
    }
    public virtual DbSet<AzureBlobs> AzureBlobs { get; set; }
}
```

Is this a bug in EF code generator or am i missing a step in model creation ?

Comment: You probably want to map both subtypes to their own tables. See TPH vs. TPT or TPC inheritance. And add an entity set name in the designer.

Comment: If you want, because Visual Studio generates partial classes, you can add a new file with the same UploadsDataModelContainer context and add the relevant properties: public DbSet<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }

Comment: @RicardoPeres That's true i will try it out and give you feedback. Thank you.

Comment: @RicardoPeres What you've suggested worked well for me.
You saved my time man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to RicardoPeres i added a class file with the following content and it resolved my problem by avoiding the automatic updates of the DbContext.cs file :

```
    public partial class UploadsDataModelContainer : DbContext
{

    public virtual DbSet<Chunk> CHunks { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Upload> Uploads { get; set; }

}
```